# Solving a system of integral equations

Tags: equation-solving

Is it possible to solve a system of integral equations in Mathematica? More specifically, I would like to obtain numerical solutions for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ from the following system:

```
f[x_] := (Sqrt[2*Pi]*σ*x*(1 - x))^(-1)*Exp[-0.5*σ^(-2)*(Log[x/(1 - x)] - μ)^2]
g[μ_, σ_] := Integrate[x*f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
h[μ_, σ_] := Integrate[x^2*f[x],{x, 0, 1}]
Solve[{g[μ, σ] == 0.3, h[μ, σ] == 0.1}, {μ, σ}]
```

The last line of code is a naive attempt to solve the system that does not run.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that Mathematica uses `Log[]` for the natural logarithm.

Comment: Oops! Have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_, μ_, σ_] := 
  (Sqrt[2*Pi]*σ*x*(1 - x))^(-1)*Exp[-0.5*σ^(-2)*(Log[x/(1 - x)] - μ)^2]
g[μ_?NumericQ, σ_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[x*f[x, μ, σ], {x, 0, 1}]
h[μ_?NumericQ, σ_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[x^2*f[x, μ, σ], {x, 0, 1}]

FindRoot[{g[μ, σ] == 0.3, h[μ, σ] == 0.1}, {{μ, 1}, {σ, 1}}]
(*{μ -> -0.894192, σ -> 0.495778}*)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! I assume I don't need to worry about the initial convergence warnings by NIntegrate?

Comment: @Miguel No, it is caused by symbolic expansion. If you feel this is annoying, first execute `Clear[f,g,h]` and then run my updated code, there should not be errors anymore. PS: that `?NumericQ` prevents the equation from symbolic expansion, so `NIntegrate` won't complain.

Comment: Thanks - that does get rid of the initial warnings. And changing the starting point for $\mu$  to 0 in your code gets rid of the remaining convergence warnings. Thanks again!